# Swift + xCode 7 constraints bad behavior

Tags: xcode, swift, position, constraints, xcode7

I have an UIImage in my storyboard and a button over it (and inside it too). I want to pin this button to the left and top margin of the UIImage in order to have it at the top left corner of the UIImage. 
I place the button at the top left corner of the image, I ctrl+drag the blue line from the button to the right side of it and inside the image and I click "top". When I try to make the same in order to select "left", there is no left at the menu! What is the problem ? What can i do to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for all that text but I cannot upload images in here.

Comment: By "left," I think you really want the "leading" edge. It should say "leading" in the pop up menu after control clicking and dragging.

Comment: there is no "leading space" or something like that...

Comment: in addition, when i set the first constraint (the "top" one) the line of the constraint is not a yellow one at the top of the UIImage but a red one at the top of the button!!

Comment: See the "red" line after the "top alignment" : http://postimg.org/image/4tdq0jq8v and the second step (there is not a "left"!): http://postimg.org/image/58rs12vt5/ does Xcode 7.1 beta have any bugs with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this menu at the bottom of your screen (or use a right clic drag in the view listed on the left pane.):

[[image: Constrains]]

Comment: Toam, this menu is used when you want to set constraints for something in regard to a neighbor , right? I want my button to align in regard to the UIImage that is inside to, not near to...

Comment: When you select the arrow next to "54", you should see your UIImage in the list. If not, you can use the other hint I gave you : right clic and drag from your button to your image in the Document Outline.

Comment: Which list? in the Align menu? Align is not "on". The other hint is the same to mine: CTRL+Drag. Nothing at all!

Comment: See the "red" line after the "top alignment" : http://postimg.org/image/4tdq0jq8v/

Comment: and the second step (there is not a "left"!): http://postimg.org/image/58rs12vt5/

Comment: You did not read all the words in both sentences ;)
The list, is the one when you clic the arrow on next to 54, not "Update Frames".
And the "right clic and drag" is not in your interface like you said in your first message but in the "Document Outline"